# How To Do click event based on name & value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html like

```
<form method="POST" action="?do=vote&page=vote-page">
          <button type="submit" name="vote_id" value="1" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Vote Now</button>
</form>
<form method="POST" action="?do=vote&page=vote-page">
          <button type="submit" name="vote_id" value="2" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Vote Now</button>
</form>
```

My question is, I want to click the button based on name and value with jquery or javascript, How to do this?

Comment: you have two forms with the same action? you might be trying a very simple thing in a very complicate way

Comment: Do you mean you want _JS to click the button for you_ based on that criteria, or when _you click on those buttons_ you want the JS to do something based on that criteria?

Comment: When you say based on name and value, do you mean something like `$("button[name=vote_id][value=2]")`?

Comment: what you doing is wrong if value in your submit represent voting candidate, then better use radio buttons and try to have only one submit button since your form action is pointing to same URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you mean, that you want to execute click if name and value attributes are matching on any button. You can try the following. You should have some event attached to that button, so you can see the effect.

I have attached onclick there and put correct names.

```js
function clickButtons(name,value){
var elements=document.getElementsByTagName("button");
 for(var i=elements.length-1;i>=0;--i)
 {
 var e=elements.item(i);
 if(name==e.name&&value==e.value)e.click();
 }
}
clickButtons("name_1",2);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="?do=vote&page=vote-page">
          <button type="submit" name="name_3" value="3" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" onclick="alert(this.name+', '+this.value)">Vote Now</button>
</form>
<form method="POST" action="?do=vote&page=vote-page">
          <button type="submit" name="name_1" value="2" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" onclick="alert(this.name+', '+this.value)">Vote Now</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You should of course put correct names and value, I have also changed that.